# mathematical question on the block-diagonalization

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra

Suppose we have a $(n+m)\times(n+m)$ matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & B \\
  B^T & C \\
 \end{pmatrix},$$
where $B$ is a $m\times n$ matrix and $C$ is a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix. Now suppose $B\ll C$ (in terms of eigenvalues), then matrix $A$ has two distinct sets of eigenvalues. $n$ of them are of order of the eigenvalues of $C$, the remaining three are suppressed by two powers of 
$$\theta=BC^{-1}.$$
One can block-diagonalize $A$ by expanding $\theta$. On one hand one obtains $m\times m$ matrix 
$$D=-\theta C\theta^T$$. On the other hand there is the $n\times n$ matrix 
$$E=C+\frac{1}{2}(\theta^\dagger\theta C+C^T\theta^T\theta^*).$$

Could anyone tell me how to do the block-diagonalization by expanding $\theta$?